# Avoiding Potential SQL Injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am building an API with RoR 4 and PostgreSQL. I want to give my users some search functionality through the index action in my controllers.
To this end I built the following function.

query_params is the result of [params.permit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) in one the controllers.

The ouput of this funcion is then sent to the active record [where](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) function.

```
def searchable (query_params)
    query = ''    
    query_params.each do |key, value|
      value = value.to_s # Ensure this is a string or you will have crashes below
      # Equals any of multiple values
      if value[/\A(mul-)/]
        value[0..3] = ''
        query += "#{key} IN (#{value}) AND "
      # Not a single value
      elsif value[/\A(<>)/]
        value[0..1] = ''
        query += "(#{key} <> #{value}) AND "    
      # Bigger or smaller than a single value
      elsif value[/\A[><]/]
        operator = value[/\A[><]/]
        value[0] = ''
        query += "(#{key} #{operator} #{value}) AND "    
      # Equals a single value
      else
        query += "#{key} = '#{value}' AND "
    
      end
    end
    query = query[0..-5] # removes the last AND
  end
```

I am worried this method opens my DB up to sql injections. Am I right? If you have an example of a possible injection that would be great. Finally, is there anything I can do to block injections?

Thanks!

Comment: should use prepared statements to mitigate against SQL injection

Comment: @smoggers how would you do that and make it dynamic, that is allow the API user to choose what to search?

Comment: There are some pretty neat solutions for searching with postgreSQL. I am thinking of the gem pg_search (https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search
If it is not enough => you might want to have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the default's ActiveRecord query functions, since they protect you from most of programmers' mistakes. Also, you should always verify the users' input before you pass it to DB queries.

The point about RoR and its Models is to abstract you from DB, making your app (almost) DB-agnostic.

By the way, this site may be helpful: http://rails-sqli.org/

EDIT: Another thing: never pass strings directly to Model's queries. Instead, just pass a hash. Example:

Don't use:

```
Model.where("id = #{params[id]}")
```

Instead use:

```
Model.where(id: params[id])
```

Comment: Did you mean "Don't use `Model.where("id = #{params[id]}")`"?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Edited. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks, the website you refer to, along with Rail's own documentation mean that this implementation is out of the question. I will search for other methods, or look into gems.

Comment: The good thing about gems is that you don't need to reinvent the wheel @Ukatz

Answer (score 0):

After reading @Miguel Cunha's answer I rewrote the code and it is now safe. I wanted to upload the changes, as I think it might be useful for others to compare. In any case I recommend looking at gems (and perhaps Elastic Search) first.

```
  # Permitted params makes sure keys cannot cause SQL injections!
  def searchable (query_params)
    query_keys = '' # Using array to prevent SQL injection
    query_values = {}  
    query_params.each do |key, value|
      value = value.to_s # Ensure this is a string or you will have crashes below

      # Equals any of multiple values
      if value[/\A(mul-)/]
        query_keys += "#{key} IN (:#{key}) AND "
        value[0..3] = ''
        query_values[key.to_sym] = value.split(',')
      # Not a single value
      elsif value[/\A(<>)/]
        query_keys += "#{key} <> :#{key} AND "
        value[0..1] = ''
        query_values[key.to_sym] = value
      # Bigger or smaller than a single value
      elsif value[/\A[><]/]
        operator = value[/\A[><]/]
        query_keys += "#{key} #{operator} :#{key} AND "
        value[0] = ''
        query_values[key.to_sym] = value   
      # Equals a single value
      else
        query_keys += "#{key} = :#{key} AND "
        query_values[key.to_sym] = value   
      end
    end
    query_keys = query_keys[0..-5] # removes the last AND
    query = [query_keys, query_values]
  end
```